# Flutter ListTile leading height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'd like to have a listtile where the `leading` widget is simply a half-transparent white container. Let me clarify it with an example

[image]

I managed to create the layout above (2 `ListTile`'s). But as you can see, when the `title` property contains a large text as it is doing in the first (the green) tile, **the height of the `leading` widget is not following as it should**. The below code returns a `ListTile` given a `Label` which is a class of my own that simply contains text, textcolor and backgroundcolor.

```
ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        dense: true,
        minLeadingWidth: 15,
        tileColor: label.bgColor,
        textColor: label.textColor,
        horizontalTitleGap: 0,
        minVerticalPadding: 0,
        trailing: getPopUpMenuButton(label),
        leading: Container(
          height: double.maxFinite,
          width: 15,
          color: Colors.white54,
        ),
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
          child: Text(
            label.title,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

So to summarize: how to make the `leading` height follow the height of the `ListTile`?

Comment: You want to 1st image is same as 2nd but white space also fit to container?

Comment: Indeed, the white container should always have the same height als the entire listtile. In the second tile of my screenshot, this is the case since the title property is a short text but in the first tile of the screenshot, the text is large and the leading height does not follow suit

Comment: Not sure, I would try this: `leading: Container(height: double.infinity, ... )`

Comment: According to the docs, the height of the leading and trailing widgets are constrained to the Material spec: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#:~:text=The%20heights%20of%20the%20leading%20and%20trailing%20widgets%20are%20constrained%20according%20to%20the%20Material%20spec.%20An%20exception%20is%20made%20for%20one%2Dline%20ListTiles%20for%20accessibility.

Comment: @DanHarms So it seems that this is intended behaviour and unfixable

Answer (score 0):

`ListTile` provide the UI with specific rules. As for leading this Size is defined within the [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1d47a1b3b2862708ee260a9a1bfc568be85459a7/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1107-L1129) as

```dart
    final BoxConstraints maxIconHeightConstraint = BoxConstraints(
      //...
      maxHeight: (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + densityAdjustment.dy,
    );
    final BoxConstraints looseConstraints = constraints.loosen();
    final BoxConstraints iconConstraints = looseConstraints.enforce(maxIconHeightConstraint);

    final double tileWidth = looseConstraints.maxWidth;
    final Size leadingSize = _layoutBox(leading, iconConstraints);
    final Size trailingSize = _layoutBox(trailing, iconConstraints);
```

The height is coming from

```
maxHeight: (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + densityAdjustment.dy,
```

We can create the custom widget using rows and column,

```dart
body: Center(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 33,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding( //use separate builder to and remove the padding
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight:
                          Radius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
                      topRight:
                          Radius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
                    )),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        "I managed to create the layout above (2 ListTile's). But as you can see, when the title property contains a large text as it is doing in the first (the green) tile, the height of the leading widget is not following as it should. The below code returns a ListTile given a Label which is a class of my own that simply contains text, textcolor and backgroundcolor.",
                        softWrap: true,
                        maxLines: 13,
                        style: TextStyle(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.menu),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am however not keen on 'faking' official widgets to make it fit some specific requirement of mine. This could introduce bugs and when the official widgets receive updates or more functionality, I wouldn't have it in my widget

Comment: You can check [the doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) as said `The heights of the leading and trailing widgets are constrained according to the Material spec.`. As for the custom widget, this totally depends on  base widgets and not sure about `bugs` you are talking about.